# Outlook webaddin Manifest - <WebApplicationInfo> resource?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have a question. I'm building an Outlook webaddin to send an email.
In my manifest I have:

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>xxxxx</Id>
      <Resource>https://graph.microsoft.com/xxxxx</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>Mail.Send</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
```

I get the error:

All URLs in the Resources section must be from the same domain and subdomain as the Resource element under the WebApplicationInfo node in the manifest. The domain and subdomain of URL https://sendtopm.xxxx/PMaddin/index.html does not match the domain and subdomain of the Resource https://graph.microsoft.com.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

I tried also to put https://graph.microsoft.com in my  <AppDomains>

Comment: WebApplicationInfo is just used for SSO. If you want to use SSO, the Resource URL you put in there probably should be your own URL, not graph? See Documentation on SSO here: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/main/docs/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins.md